# How to set up and use health check endpoints in Ktor application?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

There is a Ktor application running on port 10891. Need to configure health check endpoints on port 8080, specifically need /actuator/health/readiness. Please tell me how this can be done in the Ktor application? In Spring is spring-actuator. Is there something like that for Ktor?

Comment: There is no such out-of-the-box functionality in Ktor. I suggest trying this third-party library https://github.com/sksamuel/cohort.

Answer (score 1):

To use a different port is not possible. Now the health endpoint should say whether the service monitored is able to serve its purpose.  Therefore the minimal information that this endpoint delivers is an Http status 200. So basically you could implement it yourself, and if the service is not able to serve the requests anymore, the external observer shall react to the status different than 200.